# onPause() and onResume() functions while designing the home screen

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, onpause, application-start

I am designing an Home Screen in which I am showing the applist in a gridview.
There are some animation in the 1st screen of my HOMESCREEN and when you press on a button then a grid is shown.
So, the problem is that;
1)).I opened an application from the gridview,it opens normally but when i exit from that particular application,the BACKButton takes me to the screen of GridView.(It is OKAY).
Now,When I press the HOME Button,It is doing the same work as it does on BACKBUTTON.

I am listening to these butons using `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` but it is not working with home button..
Logically ,I should not work because this `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` works for my application not for any other application..

I found some other paths to resolve this problem,

When i open other apps,onPause() and onStop() functions are called in my homescreen,suppose I set a flag over there but by doing this How will I be able to know that after doing his stuff in OTher application user presses HOME BUTTON or BACK BUTTON.

Comment: Please tell me what you want on Home button press...

Comment: I want to show the 1st screen of my HomeScreen on which I am applying animation and providing the buttons to the user to open the gridView.

Comment: you should add finish() when user click in app icon in side gridview

Comment: when i am doing this,It takes me out of my homescreen due to finish() call.As I mentioned in my question is that I am able to detect that user has opened another application fro the gridview but how would I know that user presses BACKBUTTON or HOMEBUTTON to quit from the application.

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {   }
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) { }}

Comment: You can differentiate using above comment code

Comment: I am also using DispatchKeyEvent to differentiate the events..But when the user is in the another application's activity how can my application know about this keyevent.Because this code will be running in my app.So,I have tried but failed.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your home activity look like below code

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.android.launcher2.Launcher"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan"
            android:configChanges="locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and declare gridactivity as a normal activity in Manifest

I hope you got solution.

Answer (score 0):

`dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` won't be able to catch Home button click. if you want to capture Home button click use `onUserLeaveHint()`. 
And to capture back button specifically use `onBackPressed()`.